# Labelary Online ZPL Viewer displays incorrect unicode character (© instead of é)

Tags: unicode, zpl

I am testing my zpl code using Labelary Online ZPL Viewer. However, Labelary Online ZPL Viewer is displaying incorrect unicode character (© instead of é). Here is my code:

```
^XA  
^FT870,390^A0N,200,208^FH^FDQt_c3_a9:^FS  
^XZ
```

ZPL Viewer Output:

```
Qt©:
```

Expected Output:

```
Qté:
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Add `^CI28` to the beginning of the format to use UTF-8.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in [ZPL docs](http://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/CI_Command.pdf), using `^CI28` will provide support for UTF-8.

Working example on [labelary.com](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5ECI28%0A%5EFT50%2C390%5EA0N%2C200%2C208%5EFH%5EFDQt_c3_a9%3A%5EFS%20%20%0A%5EXZ) ([non-working version](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFT50%2C390%5EA0N%2C200%2C208%5EFH%5EFDQt_c3_a9%3A%5EFS%20%20%0A%5EXZ) too)